# Função que retorna uma nova instância de uma classe

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos

Alguém sabe me explicar pq essa função não está retornando uma nova instância. Ela retorna um objeto monstro, exatamente como eu quero, mas quando o monstro morre, a nova instância que ele retorna volta exatamente como o monstro antigo que já foi morto.

```
def new(self, name):
    monster = self._monsters.get(name) # Dicionário que contém todos os monstros
    instance = Monster(name=name) # Cria um novo monstro
    for attr in monster.__dict__:
        # Pega os atributos de um monstro existente o coloca na nova instância
        instance.__setattr__(attr, monster.__dict__[attr]) 
    return instance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

olha  - o seu projeto todo - faz umas coisas estranhas pra manipular objetos - e o código não está todo aí, fui ver no github, por conta do contato que tivemos em outra pergunta - https://github.com/ThomasCaio/.RPG . E o problema é que seus monstros diferentes (com "names" diferentes, deveriam ser *classes* diferentes - você cria tudo como uma mesma classe,   usa instâncias para um tipo de monstro - e ainda usa um esquema de "caching" pra garantir que de fato só exista uma instância  "Monster" com o mesmo "name" de cada vez.

Como o código não está todo aqui (na questão), nem fiz a análise completa, mas provavelmente o problema que você está tendo provavelmetne está relacionado com esse approach.

(Colocar quase todo o código do projeto numa questão aqui também acho que não resolveria). Talvez até dê para achar o problema pontual aí, mas eu não achei - exceto que a chamada a MonsterFactory.add nesta linha https://github.com/ThomasCaio/.RPG/blob/9f6f38a7d10303b0bed7de434a3c279c266d57ae/rpg/units.py#L346 deveria pelo menos substituir o "monstro antigo" pelo "monstro novo".  Se você está tentando ter duas instâncias de um monstro com o mesmo "name", o problema está justamente aí,  o registro de monstros dentro do "MonsterFactory" mantém apenas um monstro de cada "name" - mas uma nova instância deveria vir com os atributos zerados normalmente.

Comment: Opa. Na verdade essa versão que tá no Github ela ainda retornava certinho a nova instância. O problema é que eu tô concertando essas coisas estranhas e tá bugando tudo. O Monster pode ter várias instâncias, só o objeto que manipula os monstros que eu deixei pra ter apenas uma instância, visto que nesse objeto estaria armazenado os monstros.

Comment: Ahh tá, achei. A classe Monster tem uma linha que adiciona o monstro no factory baseado no name e substitui o monstro antigo.